# How to Prevent Automatic Activation of HDMI-Connected TV When Primary Monitors are Powered Off?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I'm using Windows 11 on an HP desktop computer with an NVidia graphics card, and I have a setup that includes two monitors and one TV. I prefer to keep the TV (connected via HDMI) disabled while using the monitors. However, when I manually power off both monitors, the TV automatically activates. This causes all my icons and open windows to rearrange, and the system often switches to a very low DPI setting. Some applications even retain this low DPI setting after I turn my monitors back on.

Is there a way to prevent my TV from automatically enabling when I shut down the two primary monitors?

Comment: Get an HDMI disconnect switch.  Easy to fond.

Comment: check the manual for your TV to see if this feature can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Simple hardware solution: use a controlled power strip, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08H2JJJ2V) (not a recommendation, just an *example*), One or more devices control power to others. These are commonly used to shut a peripheral if the computer is powered down.

Connect a monitor or two as the *controller* and the TV as the *controlled* device. Other peripherals could be switched, as well, such as printers and powered drives.

While I'd not spend much to do this, some electric utilities *give away* such power strips to help reduce loads.